# destroy session variable for logout

Tags: php, session

I want to clear the session value before redirect.In my logout.php I have session destry code.This code is working nicely If I coment line redirecting code.If I include redirecting code it get redirect before session killing.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset(); 
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
   /*
     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.location.href='login.php';
       </SCRIPT>"); 
    */ 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it via php headers and place it in the if statement so after destroying session it will redirect you to login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset(); // Also there is no need for unsetting
$_SESSION = array(); //This is useless too.

// use php header instead of javascript
if(session_destroy()) //once you destroy session it automatically unsets all keys
{
 header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ob_start()

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is
>   active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead
>   the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>
> The contents of this internal buffer may be copied into a string
>   variable using ob_get_contents(). To output what is stored in the
>   internal buffer, use ob_end_flush(). Alternatively, ob_end_clean()
>   will silently discard the buffer contents.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();

if(session_destroy())
{
 header("location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Still having problem can

Comment: this is in separate page  login.php without html.

Comment: Check it and print result : if(session_destroy())
{
 echo 1;
} else { echo 0; }

Comment: try this : <?php
session_start();
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();

if(session_destroy()){
ob_start(); 
header("location: login.php");
exit();
}
?>

Comment: still having problem sir.header is not working but session value is cleared

Comment: OK. add this code above of codes and print results : error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','10');

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/domain/public_html/sample/admin_dashboard.php:150) in /home/domain/public_html/sample/logout.php on line 10

Comment: This problem for headers. ob_start() fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

Call the redirection after the session destroy like this

```
<?php
if(session_destroy())
{
header("location: login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Raheel Khan's answer is the correct one. If **header("Location:login.php")** isn't working, verify if your code has a space before php open tag

```
<?
```

Nothing can't be sent to the browser before headers. If you send anything to browser, header redirect will not work.